# Using AlertDialog buttons to start a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I am trying to use an alertdialog to allow the user to press the ok button and open a new activity. Below is my code:

My first activity

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog=    new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dialog.setTitle("Welcome");
                dialog.setMessage("Please click ok");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.thewildOnz.myResult");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
```

the new activity

```
public class myResult extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);
```

Manifest:

```
</activity>
           <activity
        android:name=".myResult"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.thewildOnz.myResult" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFUALT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

However I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What line do you get the exception on?

Comment: startActivity(intent)

Comment: Please show the full stack trace

Comment: Don't you need to give your intent a ".class" parameter?

Comment: @j0chn do I need the .class if i've defined it in the manifest? Im new to java so still get abit confused!

Comment: look at pheonixblade's answer. There he used intent(this, com.thewildOnz.myResult.class). That's what I meant. ;) You have to give your intent a context (this) and the class which shallbe opened. Therefore you use the path (com.thewildOnz) and the explicit class (myResult.class).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `.create()` on your `AlertDialog`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Welcome");
builder.setMessage("Please click ok");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.thewildOnz.myResult");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

You also may be using new `Intent("")` incorrectly.  Unless you have `"com.thewildOnz.myResult"` defined as an action, this will fail.

You should be using this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.thewildOnz.myResult.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. When I do:

    new(Intent(this,.....)) 
It does not allow me to have this as an input, any idea why?

Comment: Still having issues with the startActivity(intent); 
even using your method the log still points to it being the error

Comment: Im still a little confused about when you said when you said 'Unless you have "com.thewildOnz.myResult" defined as an action, this will fail.' In my manifest I thought I had defined the action?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got a typo it's `DEFAULT` :

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFUALT" />
```